# Counting number of vowels in a string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I'm using basic JavaScript to count the number of vowels in a string.  The below code works but I would like to have it cleaned up a bit.  Would using `.includes()` help at all considering it is a string?  I would like to use something like `string.includes("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")` if at all possible to clean up the conditional statement.  Also, is it needed to convert the input into a string?

```
function getVowels(str) {
  var vowelsCount = 0;

  //turn the input into a string
  var string = str.toString();

  //loop through the string
  for (var i = 0; i <= string.length - 1; i++) {

  //if a vowel, add to vowel count
    if (string.charAt(i) == "a" || string.charAt(i) == "e" || string.charAt(i) == "i" || string.charAt(i) == "o" || string.charAt(i) == "u") {
      vowelsCount += 1;
    }
  }
  return vowelsCount;
}
```

Comment: in a for loop after string.length the "-1" is not needed if you don't use <"=". would look better if "=" are removed as well as "-1".

Answer (score 38):

You can actually do this with a small regex:

```
function getVowels(str) {
  var m = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
  return m === null ? 0 : m.length;
}
```

This just matches against the regex (`g` makes it search the whole string, `i` makes it case-insensitive) and returns the number of matches.  We check for `null` incase there are no matches (ie no vowels), and return 0 in that case.

Answer (score 12):

Convert the string to an array using the [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method, then use the [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter the array to contain only vowels, and then the `length` property will contain the number of vowels.

```js
const countVowels = str => Array.from(str)
  .filter(letter => 'aeiou'.includes(letter)).length;

console.log(countVowels('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')); // 5
console.log(countVowels('test')); // 1
console.log(countVowels('ddd')); // 0
```

Comment: Hello, but the filter method will remove duplicate, i mean if the string have two a's for example the filter method will only return the first one ? no ?

Answer (score 7):

```
function countVowels(subject) {
    return subject.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length;
}
```

You don't need to convert anything, Javascript's error handling is enough to hint you on such a simple function if it will be needed.

Comment: It doesn't work when `subject` doesn't contain any vowels.

Comment: `return (subject.match(/[aeiou]/gi) || []).length;`  change to this just in case

Answer (score 5):

Short and ES6, you can use the function count(str);

```
const count = str => (str.match(/[aeiou]/gi) || []).length;
```

Answer (score 4):

This could also be solved using [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method by replacing anything that isn't a vowel with an empty string (basically it will delete those characters) and returning the new string length:

```
function vowelCount(str) {
  return str.replace(/[^aeiou]/gi, "").length;
};
```

or if you prefer ES6

```
const vowelCount = (str) => ( str.replace(/[^aeiou]/gi,"").length )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the given string into an array using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and then you can [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the characters to only those which are vowels (case-insensitive).

Afterwards, you can check the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) of the array to obtain the total number of vowels in the string:

```js
const vowel_count = string => [...string].filter(c => 'aeiou'.includes(c.toLowerCase())).length;

console.log(vowel_count('aaaa'));            // 4
console.log(vowel_count('AAAA'));            // 4
console.log(vowel_count('foo BAR baz QUX')); // 5
console.log(vowel_count('Hello, world!'));   // 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this function to get the count of vowels within a string. Works pretty well.

```
function getVowelsCount(str)
{
  //splits the vowels string into an array => ['a','e','i','o','u','A'...]
  let arr_vowel_list = 'aeiouAEIOU'.split(''); 


  let count = 0;
  /*for each of the elements of the splitted string(i.e. str), the vowels list would check 
    for any occurence and increments the count, if present*/
  str.split('').forEach(function(e){
  if(arr_vowel_list.indexOf(e) !== -1){
   count++;} });


   //and now log this count
   console.log(count);}


//Function Call
getVowelsCount("World Of Programming");
```

Output for the given string would be 5. Try this out.

//Code -

```
  function getVowelsCount(str)
   {
     let arr_vowel_list = 'aeiouAEIOU'.split(''); 
     let count = 0;
     str.split('').forEach(function(e){
     if(arr_vowel_list.indexOf(e) !== -1){
     count++;} });
     console.log(count);
   }
```

Comment: Hi, you should explain your answer. So others who looks for the answer will understand. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use the simple includes function, which returns true if the given array contains the given character, and false if not.

Note: The includes() method is case sensitive. So before comparing a character convert it to lowercase to avoid missing all the possible cases.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= string.length - 1; i++) {
  if ('aeiou'.includes(string[i].toLowerCase())) {
    vowelsCount += 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `match` but be careful as it can return a **null** if no match is found. This solves it:

```
const countVowels = (subject => (subject.match(/[aeiou]/gi) || []).length);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the shortest solution

```
 function getCount(str) {
 return (str.match(/[aeiou]/ig)||[]).length;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function vowels(str) {
   let count=0;
   const checker=['a','e','i','o','u'];
   for (let char of str.toLowerCase){
      if (checker.includes(char)) {
        count++;
      }
   return count;
}


function vowels(str) {
   const match = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
   return match ? match.length : 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
count = function(a) {
  //var a=document.getElementById("t");
  console.log(a); //to see input string on console
  n = a.length;
  console.log(n); //calculated length of string
  var c = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if ((a[i] == "a") || (a[i] == "e") || (a[i] == "i") || (a[i] == "o") || (a[i] == "u")) {
      console.log(a[i]); //just to verify
      c += 1;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("p").innerText = c;
}
```

```html
<p>count of vowels </p>
<p id="p"></p>
<input id="t" />
<input type="button" value="count" onclick="count(t.value)" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const containVowels = str => {
  const helper = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

  const hash = {};

  for (let c of str) {
    if (helper.indexOf(c) !== -1) {
      if (hash[c]) {
        hash[c]++;
      } else {
        hash[c] = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  let count = 0;
  for (let k in hash) {
    count += hash[k];
  }

  return count;
};

console.log(containVowels('aaaa'));
```

Answer (score 2):

As the introduction of forEach in ES5 this could be achieved in a functional approach, in a more compact way, and also have the count for each vowel and store that count in an Object.

```
function vowelCount(str){
  let splitString=str.split('');
  let obj={};
  let vowels="aeiou";
  splitString.forEach((letter)=>{
    if(vowels.indexOf(letter.toLowerCase())!==-1){
      if(letter in obj){
        obj[letter]++;
      }else{
        obj[letter]=1;
      }
    }   

 });
 return obj;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
const str = "In West Philadephia, born and raised.";
const words = str.split("");

function getVowelCount() {
    return words.filter(word => word.match(/[aeiou]/gi)).length;
}

console.log(getVowelCount());
```

Output: 12

Answer (score 2):

You can easily solve this using simple regex. match() method matches string agains a regex variable. return an array if the is a matches and return null if no match is found.

```js
function getVowels(str) {
  let vowelsCount = 0;

  const regex = /[aiueo]/gi;
  vowelsCount = str.match(regex);

  return vowelsCount ? vowelsCount.length : 0;
}

console.log(getVowels('Hello World')) => return 3
console.log(getVoewls('bbbcccddd') => return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this function [for ES5] :

```
function countVowels(str){
    return (str.match(/[aeiou]/gi) == null) ? 0 : str.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length;        
}
```

Will work like a charm

Answer (score 1):

```
    (A)   
     const countVowels = data => [...data.toLowerCase()].filter(char => 'aeiou'.includes(char)).length;

    (B)    
      const countVowels = data => data.toLowerCase().split('').filter(char => 'aeiou'.includes(char)).length;

    countVowels("Stackoverflow") // 4
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works and is short:

```js
 function countVowels(str) {
 return ( str = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi)) ? str.length : 0;
}


console.log(countVowels("abracadabra")); // 5
console.log(countVowels(""));            // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

One more method (using `reduce`):

```
   function getVowels(str) {
     return Array.from(str).reduce((count, letter) => count + 'aeiou'.includes(letter), 0);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the my solution for the problem:

```
function getVowelsCount(s) {
      let vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
      let count=0;

    for(let v of s) {
        if(vowels.includes(v)){
            console.log(v);
            count=count+1;
        }
           
    }
     console.log(count);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After research and without using regex, this is what I found the simplest to understand for new devs like me.

```js
function vowelCount (string) {
  let vowel = "aeiouy"; // can also be array
  let result = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    
    if (vowel.includes(string[i].toLowerCase())) {
      result++;
    }
  }

    
  return result;
}



console.log(vowelCount("cAkeYE"));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
function vowelCount(str){
str=str.toLowerCase()
let count=[]
for(let i=0;i<str.length;i++){
if(str.charAt(i)=='u'||str.charAt(i)=='o'||str.charAt(i)=='i'||str.charAt(i)=='e'||str.charAt(i)=='a'){
  count.push(str.charAt(i))//to store all the vowels in an array
   }
}
let eachcount={}
count.forEach((x)=>eachcount[x]?eachcount[x]++:eachcount[x]=1) //to count each vowel from the count array
return eachcount
}
console.log(vowelCount("hello how Are You"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function vowelsCount(sentence) {
let vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"];
let count = 0;
let letters = Array.from(sentence);
letters.forEach(function (value) {
 if (vowels.includes(value)) {
  count++
   }
})
 return count;
}
console.log(vowelsCount("StackOverFlow"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to lookup characters in constant time and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to do the actual counting. The implementation also uses the [spread syntax](https://javascript.info/rest-parameters-spread) for `string` as strings are [`Iterable`](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_sync-iteration.html#iterable-iterator-iteratorresult).

```js
/**
 * Count vowels in a string. Ignores case.
 * @param {string} str String to count the vowels in
 * @returns numbers of vowels
 */
function countVowels(str) {
    let vowels = new Set("aeiou")
    return [...str.toLowerCase()].reduce((count, character) => count + vowels.has(character) || 0, 0)
};

console.log(countVowels("apple"))
console.log(countVowels("pears are yummy"))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```