# Javascript: Counting number of vowels in a string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to count the number of vowels in a string, but my counter does not seem to be returning more than one. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks!

```
var vowelCount = function(str){
  var count = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(str[i] == 'a' || str[i] == 'i' || str[i] == 'o' ||str[i] == 'e' ||str[i] == 'u'){
      count+=1;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
console.log(vowelCount('aide'));
```

Comment: `return count;` move out to for loop

Comment: try `string.match(/[aeiou]/g).length`

Comment: @Rajesh I'd use `/[aeiou]/ig`

Comment: @JaydipJ That makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks, but I am not familiar with that expression yet

Comment: @ColinSygiel regular expressions are very powerful and invaluable if you need to process strings. Start here ~ http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting number of vowels in a string with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450399/counting-number-of-vowels-in-a-string-with-javascript)

Answer (score 7):

`return count` outside of `for` loop, or use `RegExp` `/[^aeiou]/ig` as first parameter to `.replace()` with `""` as replacement string, get `.legnth` of string returned by `.replace()`

```js
vowelLength = "aide".replace(/[^aeiou]/ig, "").length;

console.log(vowelLength);

vowelLength = "gggg".replace(/[^aeiou]/ig, "").length;

console.log(vowelLength);
```

`RegExp` description

Character set

`[^xyz]` A negated or complemented character set. That is, it matches anything that is not enclosed in the brackets.

Flags

`i` ignore case

`g` global match; find all matches rather than stopping after the first match

---

Using spread element, `Array.prototype.reduce()`, `String.prototype.indexOf()` or `String.prototype.contains()` where supported

```js
const v = "aeiouAEIOU";

var vowelLength = [..."aide"].reduce((n, c) => v.indexOf(c) > -1 ? ++n : n, 0);

console.log(vowelLength);

var vowelLength = [..."gggg"].reduce((n, c) => v.indexOf(c) > -1 ? ++n : n, 0);

console.log(vowelLength);
```

---

Alternatively, instead of creating a new string or new array to get `.length` property or iterate characters of string, you can use `for..of` loop, `RegExp.prototype.test` with `RegExp` `/[aeiou]/i` to increment a variable initially set to `0` if `.test()` evaluates to `true` for the character passed.

```js
var [re, vowelLength] = [/[aeiou]/i, 0]; 

for (let c of "aide") re.test(c) && ++vowelLength;

console.log(vowelLength); 

vowelLength = 0;

for (let c of "gggg") re.test(c) && ++vowelLength;

console.log(vowelLength);
```

Comment: Using regex is much better approach.

Comment: @DarshakGajjar Yes, `i` flag is used to match case insensitive.

Comment: thnx for explaination...and what is use for g flag??

Comment: @DarshakGajjar _"`g` global match; find all matches rather than stopping after the first match"_ [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Be careful... this code might throw an error. When no matches are found, String#match returns null rather than an empty array. See [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Description).

Comment: Interesting way to fix the problem. I wasn't expecting you to adjust the code so significantly: `var vowelLength = (string.match(/[aeiou]/ig) || []).length` will also do just fine.

Comment: @gyre Negating characters which are not vowels from matches achieves same result using `String.prototype.replace()` which returns a string having a `.length` property without creating an array to get `.length` property.

Comment: I was not challenging the validity of your answer, merely offering an alternative!  :)  Both methods are still less efficient than a simple for-loop, as yours creates an unnecessary string object and mine an unnecessary array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to also do this. use **toLowerCase()** also

```
 var vowelCount = function(str){
  var count = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(str[i].toLowerCase() == 'a' || str[i].toLowerCase() == 'i' || str[i].toLowerCase() == 'o' ||str[i].toLowerCase() == 'e' ||str[i].toLowerCase() == 'u'){
      count+=1;
    }
  }
 return count;
}
vowelCount('aide')
```

Comment: First, please do not answer such basic problems. They will not add much to portal. Second, if you choose to answer, please add explanation.You are answering for readers and not just for OP

Comment: I'd just create a lowercase version of the entire string as opposed to doing it up to 5 times for each character