# How to return number of vowels in a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, loops, if-statement

I would be delighted if someone could look into my code. I have been trying to return the **total number of vowels** in a given string. I want my code to take into account of **cases of the letter**, any **empty spaces** in the string and also **absence of vowel**. I believe there is something wrong with my **if-statement** which is **returning 0** for the string input "Crypt" and "Crypto"

```
function countVowels(str) {

  let count = 0;
  let arr = str.toLowerCase().split("")
  let vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
  console.log(arr)

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if (arr[i].includes(vowels)){
      count++
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  }
  return count 

}
console.log(countVowels("Crypto"))
console.log(countVowels("Crypt"))
```

Comment: `(arr[i].includes(vowels))` - other way around.

Comment: `array.includes(searchElement);` You search your arr[i] in the vowels array.

Comment: There are numerous problems. You also `return 0` immediately as soon as you find the first non-vowel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting number of vowels in a string with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450399/counting-number-of-vowels-in-a-string-with-javascript)

Comment: Language is complicated, especially if you might be running this code over user-generated content. Even if you can guarantee the strings will be English, what result would you expect for borrowed words with accents such as `'Café'`?

Comment: You could produce an array of vowels in the string with `str.match(/[aeiou]/ig);` and then return the size of the array. (I don't know Javascript--an informed guess of the syntax.)

Comment: @Raiyan I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with the code you've produced here.

The first is that, for each letter in the string, you're checking whether the letter includes the array of vowels, which will never be true. You've effectively written this...

```
"a".includes(["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"])
```

which is backwards.

Instead you need to ask the array whether it includes the given, letter, this way:

```
["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].includes("a") // true
["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].includes("s") // false
```

The second problem is that, in your `else` branch, you `return 0`. This will immediately halt your function and return `0` the first time you encounter a non-vowel. Instead of `return 0`, you can simply take no action, and drop the `else` branch entirely.

Ultimately your loop should look like this:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if (vowels.includes(arr[i])) {
      count++
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop, the expression:

```
arr[i].includes(vowels)
// It should be...
vowels.includes(arr[i])
```

`.includes()` is a String and an Array method so it can be confusing to a novice. In general, you want to prefix the method with array or string that serves as the filter (the string/array used to compare with the input value).

Also, the `else` statement will short-circut your function because `return` ends the whole function immediately. The `if` statement is sufficient, if there isn't a match then the `for` loop will just ignore it.

```js
function countVowels(str) {
  let count = 0;
  let arr = str.toLowerCase().split("");
  let vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (vowels.includes(arr[i])) {
      count++
    }
  }
  return count;
}
console.log(countVowels("Crypto"))
console.log(countVowels("Crypt"))
```

As a more efficient alternative use `.filter()` like so and return `V.length`:

```
const V = array.filter(char => vowels.includes(char));
```

```js
function countVowels(str) {
  let array = str.toLowerCase().split("");
  const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  const V = array.filter(char => vowels.includes(char));
  return V.length;
};

console.log(countVowels("Crypto"))
console.log(countVowels("Crypt"))
```

Answer (score 1):

there are a lo of solution to this.

i think you are just starting so i hope following will help

```
function countVowels(str) {

  let count = 0;
  let arr = str.toLowerCase().split("");
  

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] === "a" || arr[i] === "e" || arr[i] === "i" || arr[i] === "o" || arr[i] === "u")){
//same as count++ but good practice
     count+=1
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  }
  return count 

}
console.log(countVowels("Crypto"))
console.log(countVowels("Crypt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Language is complicated. There are more vowel characters in English than are contained in the array `['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']`, mainly because of accents that show up in borrowed words such as "Café".

So before you try to detect vowels in a string, you may want to decompose it using [String.prototype.normalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) with the `'NFD'` flag to decompose accented characters into their base and a control character.

For an unaccented string, such as `'Testing'`, the result should be identical to the input. But for an accented string, such as `'Café'`, the result will decompose any accented characters into their base character and a control character:

```js
console.log(('Café').normalize('NFD').split(''));
```

Once you've done this decomposition, then you can use your list of unmodified vowels. I'd recommend using [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to convert the string into an array, and then [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove all non-vowel characters from the array so you can read its length:

```js
function getNumVowels(str) {
  const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

  const decomposedStr = str.toLowerCase().normalize('NFD');
  const strArray = decomposedStr.split('');
  
  const vowelArr = strArray.filter((char) => vowels.includes(char));
  
  return vowelArr.length;
}

console.log(getNumVowels('Testing')); // <- 2
console.log(getNumVowels('Café')); // <- 2
console.log(getNumVowels('thfds ')); // <- 0
```

Comment: this a well thought out code. Very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It should be `Array.includes(string)` instead of `String.includes(Array)`.

**Working Demo :**

```js
function countVowels(str) {

  let count = 0;
  let arr = str.toLowerCase().split("")
  let vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (vowels.includes(arr[i])) {
      count++
    }
  }
  return count;

}
console.log(countVowels("Crypto")) // 1
console.log(countVowels("Crypt")) // 0
```